# WCF determine if JSON key sent to server even if value is null

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, rest

I am performing a `PUT` request to update information about a user. Only the keys that I send in my `JSON` request require modification. This works well but I would like to include the ability for information to be deleted.

Currently when I send in the request `{"firstname": "will"}`, WCF will de-serialize the object and return the data contract. This results in an object similar to:

```
UserObject
    firstname => will,
    lastname => null,
    gender => null
```

This is fine, because I only update the values that are not null. However, when it comes to removing a value I send up `{"firstname": null}` - The fact that I sent the key determines that action that I would like it updating, omitting the other keys means it will leave them alone.

The problem is the automatic deserialisation gives me an object like:

```
UserObject
    firstname => null,
    lastname => null,
    gender => null
```

How am I to know what keys the real request had in order for me to update the values. Do I have to look at manually de-serializing the request and loop over the values? Or is there a way for the data contact to only give me the options that the request had?

I have tried `emitDefaultValue=false` but this seems to only be for serialising the object.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would introduce some kind of User-ID. The problem you have, is that your primary-key (in database language) can change, which is not a good idea.

An id does not change, and therefore you can always identify the object.

Comment: Sorry - There is a primary key in the database, the end point I send the data to is /user/{:userID} - If I want the user to be able to remove information - I would like to be able to send {"firstname": null} and for WCF to know that I want to remove the first name of the user with the ID of x.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not possible. In your WCF operation you only get deserialized object and you can only interpret null in one way. As you noticed WCF will produce the same object whether you explicitly set value to null on do not send that information.

As I see it you can send default value if you want property removed. For example for string you would send empty string and in that way your update procedure will correctly update value to empty string effectively removing it. For other types you can also send some defaults.

for example:

```
{"firstname": ""}
```

Comment: This is the work around that we have employed, but not great for handing numeric types, or nullable booleans.  I'm still researching - If I don't find anything you will be duly rewarded.

Comment: I think the problem here is that for example nullable boolean is not enough for your use case. It has three states (true, false, null) and you need four (true, false, not sent, null). So potential solution would be to create you own types with states that you need and to influence WCF deserialization process (by implementing custom IDispatchMessageFormatter).